# Android rotating webview in fragment causes not to remember state

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I am trying to prevent loosing of webview state on rotation changes here is my fragment code :

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mArticleId, imageUrl;
    private WebView mContent;
    private ImageView mBackground;
    private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;

    public static ContentFragment newInstance(String idcko) {
        ContentFragment f = new ContentFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("idcko", idcko);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
        mArticleId = getArguments().getString("idcko");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, null);
        mContent = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.content_web);
        if (webViewBundle == null) {
            new FetchContent().executeOnExecutor(
                    AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
        } else {
            Log.e("else", "");
            mContent.restoreState(webViewBundle);
        }
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        mContent.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }

    private class FetchContent extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private JSONParser jsonParser;
        private String content;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            List<NameValuePair> parametre = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parametre.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post_id", mArticleId));
            JSONObject jObj = jsonParser
                    .getJSONFromUrlNonHtml(
                            "http://www.androidaci.net/api/get_post/",
                            parametre, "GET");
            try {
                JSONObject post = jObj.getJSONObject("post");
                content = post.getString("content");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return content;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mContent.loadDataWithBaseURL("", removePlayStore(result),
                    "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

        }
    }
```

I load the content from website in HTML form, I modify it a bit with JSOUP and I show it, it works on first try, but upon rotation changes I loose the state. How can I save this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this code work, I needed to remove this line from `onCreate`:

```
this.setRetainInstance(true);
```